# Outlook creates IMAP folders two (or more) levels deep with dovecot ... where are they?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, dovecot

I'm dealing with an issue where messages were stored two levels deep in an Outlook 2016 IMAP profile.  The IMAP server is dovecot.

Like:

```
INBOX/
    folder1/
        folder1sub1/
        folder1sub2/
        ...
    folder2/
        folder2sub1/
        folder2sub2/
        ...
    ...
```

Given that dovecot doesn't support inferior mailboxes in its default configuration (which this server is using), it's perplexing how this is even possible; dovecot shouldn't even *allow* creation of the 2nd-level subfolders (`folder1sub1`...).

For unrelated reasons, the server name in the IMAP profile was changed (actually pointing to the same physical server using a different domain name), which seems to have caused Outlook to loose these 2nd-level subfolders.

I'm suspecting at this [![enter image description here][1]][1]point that Outlook is performing some behind-the-scenes trickery to appear that it's storing IMAP folders on the server, when it reality, it's storing them locally ... somewhere.

I've loaded up an OST/PST viewer to see if they are "secretly" kept somewhere by Outlook, but they are nowhere to be found.  Are these folders/messages just plain gone?

---

**EDIT**

After some additional testing, I can confirm that Outlook does, in fact, **delete** messages **without warning** when:

- the IMAP server does not support "inferior folders" (nested folders more than 1 level deep)
- Outlook contains subfolders in the IMAP tree marked **(This computer only)**
- the IMAP server name is changed (even if it's actually the same user on the same server by domain alias or IP)

Despite indicating that they are stored offline, it's unbelievable that it would just outright delete them without warning.  That is some insanely bad software design.

Comment: How do you know that the server is using Dovecot's default configuration? Have you checked the physical storage (mailbox files on the server)?

Comment: I have shell access to the server.  I can confirm it's using the default configuration that prevents inferior folders, and the missing folders are not on the server.

Comment: Could you post results produced by `doveconf mail_location`?

Comment: @AnFi: `mail_location = mbox:~/mail/:INBOX=mbox`